# XSLT mapping help required for the below given format

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<i>
   <Row>
     <Column  name="RecordID"  sqltype="nvarchar">COMPANY00022639</Column>
     <Column  name="product_name"  sqltype="nvarchar">GeoBeacon</Column>
   </Row>
   <Row>
     <Column name="RecordID" sqltype="nvarchar">COMPANY000226</Column>
     <Column name="product_name" sqltype="nvarchar">GeoExplorer 2005 Series</Column>
   </Row>
</i>
```

and I need to map each column into below format of xml

```
<i> 
    <xsd:complexType name="remedyResponseObject">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Company_ID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="product_name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType> 
</i>
```

I need to map each column of every row into two different variables where RecordID into Company_ID and product_name into product_name in my xml.
Can somebody help me on this.

At the end I need my result set as below

```
<i>
<remedyResponseObject>
<Company_ID>COMPANY00022639</Company_ID>
<product_name>GeoBeacon</product_name></remedyResponseObject>
<remedyResponseObject>
<Company_ID>COMPANY000226</Company_ID>
<product_name>GeoExplorer 2005 Series</product_name>
</remedyResponseObject>
</i>
```

Comment: What xslt did you try?

Comment: Would it be possible to show the output you are trying to achieve in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi I have updated the xml format, where I would like to map it. Please tell me if that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mapping into 'variables' here, you are actually mapping your **Column** elements to other elements. Saying 'variable' in the context of XSLT may suggest you wanted to use **xsl:variable** which is not the case here.

Still, to do the mapping is straight-forward. You can simply create a template to match the **Column** element you need to change, and output the new element you wish to map to.

For example, for creating the **Company_ID** element, the template would look this

```
<xsl:template match="Column[@name='RecordID']">
    <Company_ID><xsl:value-of select="." /></Company_ID>
</xsl:template>
```

And similarly for the **product** name.

The only other template would be one to match the root **i** element, where all you need to do is output the same **i** element, along with a **remedyResponseObject** element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="i">
        <xsl:copy>
            <remedyResponseObject>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </remedyResponseObject>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Column[@name='RecordID']">
        <Company_ID><xsl:value-of select="." /></Company_ID>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Column[@name='product_name']">
        <product_name><xsl:value-of select="." /></product_name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<i>
   <remedyResponseObject>
      <Company_ID>COMPANY00022639</Company_ID>
      <product_name>GeoBeacon</product_name>
      <Company_ID>COMPANY000226</Company_ID>
      <product_name>GeoExplorer 2005 Series</product_name>
   </remedyResponseObject>
</i>
```